# parse xml content in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, parsing

REQUIREMENT: SiteMap XML fetcher/parser to get whole map of site and parse XML content to extract source website URL (Using cron job)

DESCRIPTION:
A sitemap.xml parser should also be implemented to get the whole map of the website, or in the case that there is no RSS feeds available.

1. A sitemap.xml parser should also be implemented to get the whole map of the website, or in the case that there is no RSS feeds available. There can be multiple SiteMaps for some websites. Source of Sitemaps details will be `sitemaps` table in which data feeding will be done from ActiveAdmin interface.
2. This parser should be implemented as independent ruby program (ruby/sitemap_parser.rb) so that it can executed as standalone script which will communicate with database used ActiveAdmin. Required models for this ruby program should be in ruby/lib/models.

### MY CODE:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'active_resource'

class SitemapParser
  url = "http://railsjob.com/jobs/2040-Ruby-on-Rails-developer-Sydney-Australia.xml"
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  puts doc.at_css("title").text
  doc.css(".item").each do |item|
  title = item.at_css(".prodLink").text
  price = item.at_css(".PriceCompare .BodyS, .PriceXLBold").text[/\$[0-9\.]+/]
  puts "#{title} - #{price}"
  puts item.at_css(".prodLink")[:href]
end

class Sitemap < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://localhost:3000/admin/"
  self.user = "USER@XXX.com"
  self.password = "XXX"
end

s = Sitemap.all
puts s.inspect


end
```

---

What changes should I make, and what should I code in models?

Comment: The typical way to parse XML in Ruby is to use REXML [Try This Reference](http://developer.yahoo.com/ruby/ruby-xml.html)

Answer (score 1):

To load your rails application environment you must `require` the `environment.rb`which is located in the config folder of your application!

```
require 'config/environment.rb'
```

You can simply get the content of the page using Nokogiri and use nokogiri as a parser or you can also fetch the source of page and use `Hash.from_xml(<your_xml_here>)`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I was doing parse with `Nokogiri` with no luck, because of super different parsing than I'm similar to in Rails. Thanks!